# Sending email via AWS Lambda with SES into C#

Tags: c#, node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-ses

I have created one AWS Lambda function using Visual Studio and C# with .net core1.0

I have to send an email after doing some operation on my Lambda function.
My code is as below. taken from [AWS Doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-sdk-net.html)

```
using Amazon.DynamoDBv2;
using Amazon.DynamoDBv2.Model;
using Amazon.Lambda.Core;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Amazon.SimpleEmail;
using Amazon.SimpleEmail.Model;
using Amazon;

namespace MyProject
{
    public class AddAlarms
    {
        private static AmazonDynamoDBClient client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();

        public string AddAlarmsHandler(GetUserAlerts input, ILambdaContext context)
        {

            var client = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
            List<string> toAddress = new List<string>();
            toAddress.Add("ToEmail@domain.com");

            var sendRequest = new SendEmailRequest
            {
                Source = "sourceEmail@domain.com",
                Destination = new Destination
                {
                    ToAddresses = toAddress
                },
                Message = new Message
                {
                    Subject = new Content("Subject of email"),
                    Body = new Body
                    {
                        Html = new Content
                        {
                            Charset = "UTF-8",
                            Data = "Hello Email, HTML Body"
                        },
                        Text = new Content
                        {
                            Charset = "UTF-8",
                            Data = "Hello email, Text Body"
                        }
                    }
                },
                ConfigurationSetName = "ConfigSet"
            };
            string returnval = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sending email using Amazon SES...");
                returnval += "Sending email using Amazon SES...";
                var response = client.SendEmailAsync(sendRequest);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                returnval += ", Response Status - " + response.Status.ToString() + " - ";
                Console.WriteLine("The email was sent successfully.");
                returnval += "The email was sent successfully.....";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                returnval += "The email was not sent.";
                Console.WriteLine("The email was not sent.");
                returnval += "Error message: " + ex.Message;
                Console.WriteLine("Error message: " + ex.Message);
            }

            return returnval;
        }
    }
}
```

so Lambda function created successfully and it shows in section of Lambda into AWS

so while testing this function i get response that after sending - **"Faulted"**
and email not received by receiver.

I have verified both email TO and FROM into email verification of AWS SES.

I get one Node.Js code which runs successfully and also receiving email and node.js code i have taken from [link](http://www.wisdomofjim.com/blog/sending-an-email-from-aws-lambda-function-in-nodejs-with-aws-simple-email-service)

I have checked ROLE and using same role for Node.Js code and works fine, but for C# lambda function i am getting response "Faulted".

Please help to solve this problem in AWS Lambda

Comment: Check Amazon website for Smtp settings.  The port number and credentials are missing in your code.

Comment: as per this link 0 http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-sdk-net.html it is not needed.

Comment: Did you read the Prerequisites?

Comment: still not working. :(

Comment: What error message are you getting?  What version of Net Library are you using?  Can you send any emails? (sometimes the first email goes through and 2nd fails).

Comment: It's done today. Actually I have missed one configuration to set - it is ConfigurationSetName = "ConfigSet" - this I have to set from configuration section of ses in aws console. I have created and put that name here and it works fine now. Thanks for guidance in configuration direction which I have missed.